# How to Read Respose form a WebAPI in ReactJS

Tags: json, ajax, reactjs, asp.net-web-api, reactjs.net

I'm not able to read the **`Response`** in the ReactJS code, but the API Call is returning the proper JSON data with `Response Code: 200`

My ReactJS code is

```
 fetch('http://localhost:8090/api/Contact/GetContactType', {mode: 'no-cors'})
            .then(response=> {
                console.log(response.data);
                console.log(response);

            });
```

The Web API is returning the following JSON to the browser

```
[
   {
      "ContactTypeId":1,
      "ContactType":"Seller"
   },
   {
      "ContactTypeId":2,
      "ContactType":"Re-Seller"
   }
]
```

Kindly help me to read the following JSON using **`ReactJS`**

**Response of Answer** : **@OB3**:

I tried the same, but I'm getting the Exception. Kindly refer the Screenshot and help me.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You would have to parse the response body first.

```
fetch('http://localhost:8090/api/Contact/GetContactType', {mode: 'no-cors'})
    .then(function(response) {
        return response.json()
    }).then(function(json) {
        console.log('parsed json', json)
    }).catch(function(ex) {
        console.log('parsing failed', ex)
    })
```

Comment: could you please print the json object using `console.log()`

Comment: It does that in the second `then` block.

Comment: Is it possible that the server returns an invalid json response? could you post a screenshot of the response? (under the "network" tab)

Comment: Are you using polyfill version of fetch? if yes, ```mode: no-cors``` might not be implemented. Its documented on official website.. but it doesnt mean that https://github.com/github/fetch has it :)  - just a hint/guess, maybe this causes some trouble.